# Unable to get NSEnumerator to display next item in my array

Tags: xcode4, nsarray, nsenumerator

I am new to Objective-C and I have researched this online for weeks now. Almost every example is the same on every site and does not fully make it clear to me how to integrate it into my code for an Xcode 4 App.

The example seen everywhere is:

`NSEnumerator* theEnum = [some_array objectEnumerator];
    id obj; or id some_object = NULL;
    while(obj = [theEnum nextObject]) {
    //do something...`

I think if I better understood what id some_object = NULL;/ id obj; represents I could figure it out on my own.

In my code I have three arrays. I want to be able to display one object in each array in a UILabel field every time the user clicks the Next button until all of them have been displayed.

```
NSArray1 = 1,2,3
```

NSArray2 = John, Jill, Josh
NSArray3 = boy, girl, boy

When the next button is pushed you would see 1, John and boy. The next time you would see 2, Jill and girl and finally 3, Josh and boy.

Below is basic example, not my actually code.

```
number = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
name = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"John",@"Jill",@"Josh", nil];
gender = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"boy",@"girl",@"boy", nil];

NSEnumerator *enum = [number objectEnumerator];
id obj; (??What is this?? And how to connect to the statement below??)

while ((obj = [enumNumber nextObject])) {

self.numberItem.text = ??
self.nameItem.text = ??
self.genderItem.text = ??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`id obj` is just the variable containing the current variable you're looking at. In this code, since your `NSArray`s all contain string, you could use `NSString *obj` instead.

An enumerator can only enumerate one collection at a time. If you want to loop through all three of them together, use a traditional `for` loop:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < number.count; i++) {
    self.numberItem.text = [number objectAtIndex:i];
    self.nameItem.text = [name objectAtIndex:i];
    self.genderItem.text = [gender objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining an enumerator and providing the example for loop. When I click next in my app it is jumping from the first object (1) to the last object (10) for all three arrays and skipping 2-9. I am working on that now.

Comment: The for loop shown above will go through the entire array without waiting for input. If you want to increment by one each time a button is clicked, you need to make the current position in the array an instance variable, and then increment that by 1 each time the button is clicked. You don't need a loop to do that.

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to get it working with the instance variable like you suggested.